# Why do I get inflate exception for MvvmCross.MvxGridView?

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I think I have done everything to add a MvxGridView to my Fragment, but I still get `Error inflating class Mvx.MvxGridView` or rather `ClassNotFoundException`, but why?

Xamarin Studio on OS X, `Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.dll` is referenced.

What have I missed?

My Main activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I populate the FrameLayout with a Fragment:

```
SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
    .Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment)
    .Commit();
```

My Fragment:

```
   public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
      this.HasOptionsMenu = true;
      var ignored = base.OnCreateView (inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
      var view = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.fragment_main, null);
     /* ... ... ... */
    }
```

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Mvx.MvxGridView
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:padding="@dimen/standard_padding"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Stations; ItemClick PlayCommand"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_station"
        android:numColumns="@integer/station_columns"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/standard_padding"
        android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/standard_padding"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Stacktrace:

```
Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class Mvx.MvxGridView
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod (intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) [0x00064] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.12-series/7f0e3d3c/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:194
  at Android.Views.LayoutInflater.Inflate (int,Android.Views.ViewGroup) [0x00043] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.12-series/7f0e3d3c/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-19/src/generated/Android.Views.LayoutInflater.cs:575
  at MyApp.Droid.MainFragment.OnCreateView (Android.Views.LayoutInflater,Android.Views.ViewGroup,Android.OS.Bundle) [0x00019] in /Users/magnusjohansson/Projects/QuickApp/MyApp.Droid/Fragments/MainFragment.cs:46
  at at Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment.n_OnCreateView_Landroid_view_LayoutInflater_Landroid_view_ViewGroup_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00026, 0x000ee>
  at at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.4f99b429-b0b6-4522-936d-562081396c11 (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00023, 0x00037>
  at --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
  at android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class Mvx.MvxGridView
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
  at at MyApp.droid.MainFragment.n_onCreateView(Native Method)
  at at MyApp.droid.MainFragment.onCreateView(MainFragment.java:39)
  at at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
  at at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
  at at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
  at at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
  at at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
  at at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
  at at MyApp.droid.helpers.MvxActionBarEventSourceActivity.n_onStart(Native Method)
  at at MyApp.droid.helpers.MvxActionBarEventSourceActivity.onStart(MvxActionBarEventSourceActivity.java:78)
  at at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
  at at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
  at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
  at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
  at at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  at Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "Mvx.MvxGridView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.perfinica.MyApp-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.perfinica.MyApp-1, /system/lib]]
  at at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
  at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
  at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
  at ... 28 more
```

Comment: Is that an exact copy+paste? Because `</LinearLayout>` is not properly closed.

Comment: Take a look at some of the fragment samples - you'll see the syntax they use for inflate axml - something like bindinginflate

Comment: Thanks @Stuart, that was it! Please put it as an answer so I can properly award you.

Comment: @Kiliman, sorry a copy/paste/format edit issue. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What I see is to modify the following lines of code in My Fragment class to solve the issue.

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }
```

to:

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var ignore = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        return this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_main, null);
    }
```